# customlist in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, list, qt4

I want to create a Custom List which will contain not only a single line text but a combination of text, images buttons, progressbars. Is there any way to do this? I am unable to create that.

Please help me.

Comment: will the combination be in a single line, iow one line with text, images, buttons, etc. Or do you want one line to be text, another one to be a progress bar and another one to be a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [QTableWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtablewidget.html) where you can [display a widget in a cell](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget).

In your case you can do this:

1. Create a custom widget with buttons, progress bar, etc.
2. Implement a QTableView with only one column
3. Insert an instantiate custom widget in each row you are using

This should do what you want to achieve